# Cannot get stat_cor to position correctly to the bottom when y has negative values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have the following

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= nlk_percent ,y= c_percent, color=nlk)) +
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0), size=7, alpha=.3) + 
  geom_smooth(method=lm
              , se=FALSE
              , fullrange=TRUE
  )+
  theme_classic() +  
  stat_cor(
    method = "pearson", label.x.npc = .65, label.y.npc = 0 
  )
```

this produces the following plot,
[image]

however even when I set labe.y.npc to 0 or "bottom" the labels will stay in the middle. Is there anyway around this? I would like to place this at the bottom right of the plot.

thank you in advance.

Here is the dataframe.

```
df=structure(list(nlk = c("nlk_active", "nlk_rest", "nlk_active", 
"nlk_rest", "nlk_rest", "nlk_active", "nlk_rest", "nlk_active", 
"nlk_active", "nlk_rest", "nlk_active", "nlk_rest", "nlk_rest", 
"nlk_active", "nlk_rest", "nlk_active", "nlk_active", "nlk_rest", 
"nlk_active", "nlk_rest", "nlk_rest", "nlk_active"), nlk_percent = c(3.18269229751619, 
4.82171021503467, 2.29865831556452, 3.65306001710456, 5.61618123133188, 
3.35895882583233, 5.23610988988963, 3.10768786931437, 4.72410451986685, 
5.55642941544957, 2.88752527074159, 4.08406426478847, 5.69209237542757, 
3.64270157183323, 5.73335434061383, 3.99367436175058, 2.52857131887076, 
6.01100356443267, 3.79493566280354, 4.67016051412663, 4.73822740036724, 
3.96993327469786), c_percent = c(4.18507363787676, 4.18507363787676, 
1.13750352374994, 1.13750352374994, 3.35049724708413, 3.35049724708413, 
3.12928301694497, 3.12928301694497, 2.59215800212536, 2.59215800212536, 
0.263034405833794, 0.263034405833794, 5.05093696522523, 5.05093696522523, 
4.41751500288509, 4.41751500288509, 4.60880924267552, 4.60880924267552, 
0.748461233004036, 0.748461233004036, 0.124328135002202, 0.124328135002202
)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 10L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 
21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 34L, 36L, 37L, 39L, 42L, 44L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the description it is normalized between 0 and 1, of the parent coordinates so, what it does is really choose a point some percent of the natural range. Because there are no negative Y values you cannot use that to place the label below Zero.

Because there is no real reason to show negative values at all the easiest thing to do is set the y-limit of the plot to say -.15and then it will look better.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x= nlk_percent ,y= c_percent, color=nlk)) +
geom_point(position = position_jitter(width = 0.05, height = 0), size=7, alpha=.3) + 
geom_smooth(method=lm
            , se=FALSE
            , fullrange=TRUE
)+
ylim(-.15, 6)+
theme_classic() +  
stat_cor(
    method = "pearson", label.x.npc  =.68 , label.y.npc =.025
)
```

[image]